# java.io.NotSerializableException: androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

Putting my app on the background or changing into another app, makes my app crash in the background with the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com...MyFragment).
...
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy
```

The part of the code which happens is a viewModel on my fragment

```
private val mPlayVM: PlayViewModel by viewModels()
```

The solution I'm used to is putting the @Transient tag, but it doesn't accept ("This annotation is not applicable to target member property with delegate"). Another solution was making my classes to implement Serializable, but none actually worked.

This is the beggining of my PlayViewModel class

```
@HiltViewModel
class PlayViewModel @Inject constructor() : PlayViewModel(), Serializable {
...
}
```

Why does it crash because of Serializable on a ViewModel?

Full stack trace

```
2022-05-30 19:21:45.481 17378-17378/com.myproj E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myproj, PID: 17378
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com...MyFragment)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:2125)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1895)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:987)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1620)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1303)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1056)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(FragmentState.java:159)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedObject(Parcel.java:1749)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1628)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1585)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManagerState.java:64)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1916)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1822)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:987)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1620)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1303)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1056)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(FragmentState.java:161)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedObject(Parcel.java:1749)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1628)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1585)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManagerState.java:64)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1916)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1822)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:987)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1620)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1303)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1056)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1813)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:987)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1620)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1303)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1056)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1813)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:987)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1620)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1303)
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityTaskManager.java:4969)
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:145)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8645)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
     Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1240)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1604)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1565)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1488)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1234)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:354)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:2120)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1895) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:987) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1620) 
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1056) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(FragmentState.java:159) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedObject(Parcel.java:1749) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1628) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1585) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManagerState.java:64) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1916) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1822) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:987) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1620) 
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1056) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(FragmentState.java:161) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedObject(Parcel.java:1749) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1628) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1585) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManagerState.java:64) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1916) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1822) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:987) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1620) 
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1056) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1813) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:987) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1620) 
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1056) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1813) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:987) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1620) 
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1303) 
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityTaskManager.java:4969) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:145) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8645) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Edit: some more code for clarifications

There is an Adapter for the ViewPager

```
class AdapterVPGens(
    fragment: Fragment,
    private val mGenList: MutableList<Generator>,
    private val mIAdventurePlay: IAdventurePlay,
    private val mAdvList: MutableList<AdvList>
) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {
    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return FragmentGenInstance.newInstance(
            mGenList[position],
            mIAdventurePlay,
            mAdvList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = mGenList.size
}
```

For which is created on my initial fragment and passed into my vp

```
val adapterVPGens = AdapterVPGenerators(this, mGensList, this, advList)
binding.viewPagerGens.adapter = adapterVPGens
```

The third argument is an interface `IAdventurePlay` which the initial fragment implements, that's why the `this` on constructor. The `IAdventurePlay` has just some basic functions for the viewPager fragments to call. The initial fragment has different objects like the viewModel, some organizers/managers/etc, but none are passed into the adapter, only the current fragment and some lists of objects. The functions inherited from the interface, they do have some implementations using different objects, but again, none are passed into the adapter or any bundle (at least not intended)

Just to clarify, even though the initial fragment is "passed as an argument", only the interface  inheritance is used. The viewPager fragments can't call any objects from the initial fragment

Comment: Are you attempting to put your viewmodel into the saved instance state `Bundle` or something? You might consider editing your question and providing the full stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare Not that i know, what happens is that I have a viewPager on screen which is the main reason why others objects needs to implement Serializable or @ Transient, and yet im not passing this viewModel into the viewPager. Edited with full stack

Comment: Are you trying to pass a `ViewModel` as part of your `Bundle` of arguments to a fragment? That's never correct. It sounds like this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) where it would be helpful if you started with your original problem (which seems like trying to communicate between a fragment in a ViewPager and some other fragment/your activity?) and include your actual code where you are attempting to use that ViewModel.

Comment: @ianhanniballake i do pass the initial fragment using `this` as an interface i need to pass for the viewPager adapter. I can try to remove the `this` call by creating an object. Yet, could there be a solution for the viewModel crashing for not being Serialazable?

Comment: What you're doing is completely the wrong way to even approach the problem: there is never, ever, ever a case where your ViewModel should be `Serializable` or ever be part of your saved instance state. You need to include more of your code and what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @ianhanniballake i edited with more code and clarifications